# Mathematical Manipulation based on Condition in other columns R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe below where for each `ID` group, I want to create a new column that calculates the difference between `daystoevent` of the first instance where `excision == 1` and `died == 1`.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), daystoevent = c(19116, 
19201, 19399, 19416, 17017, 17036, 17085, 17017, 17036, 17085
), excision = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), died = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))

#    ID daystoevent excision died
# 1   1       19116        0    0
# 2   1       19201        1    0
# 3   1       19399        0    0
# 4   1       19416        0    0
# 5   2       17017        1    0
# 6   2       17036        0    0
# 7   2       17085        0    1
# 8   3       17017        1    0
# 9   3       17036        1    0
# 10  3       17085        0    1
```

Comment: What's the expected output? `ID=1` has no instance of `died=1`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr::summarise` here with some indexing:

```
df %>% 
  summarise(newcol = daystoevent[died == 1][1] - daystoevent[excision == 1][1], 
            .by = ID)
```

Output:

```
  ID newcol
1  1     NA
2  2     68
3  3     68
```

---

If you want to only include those with `died` values of 1, add a `filter`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(died == 1)) %>%
  summarise(newcol = daystoevent[died == 1][1] - daystoevent[excision == 1][1])

#     ID newcol
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     2     68
#2     3     68
```

Or if you want to replace the `NA` in those with no `died` values of 1, add a `replace`:

```
df %>% 
  summarise(newcol = daystoevent[died == 1][1] - daystoevent[excision == 1][1], .by = ID) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), "Did not die")

#  ID      newcol
#1  1 Did not die
#2  2          68
#3  3          68
```

Answer (score 1):

`match()` will find the first occurrence (if the data have been timely sorted). If no match is found, it defaults to return `NA`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(diff = diff(daystoevent[c(match(1, excision), match(1, died))]),
         .by = ID)

#    ID daystoevent excision died diff
# 1   1       19116        0    0   NA
# 2   1       19201        1    0   NA
# 3   1       19399        0    0   NA
# 4   1       19416        0    0   NA
# 5   2       17017        1    0   68
# 6   2       17036        0    0   68
# 7   2       17085        0    1   68
# 8   3       17017        1    0   68
# 9   3       17036        1    0   68
# 10  3       17085        0    1   68
```